# Group homomorphism, the uniqueness of k for g' = gk

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Group homomorphism is  $ \Phi: G \rightarrow H $

Show, that for all $ h \in H $ and all $ g,g' \in \Phi^{-1}(\{h\}) $ there exists a unique $k \in \ker(\Phi) $, so that $g'=gk$.

$$
\forall h \in H, \forall g,g' \in \Phi^{-1}(\{h\})\exists! k \in \ker(\Phi): g'=gk
$$

I do not want a solution for this problem, just maybe a hint or a first step into the right direction, because I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Look at $\Phi(g^{-1}g)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;K:=\ker\Phi\lhd G$$

$$(2)\;\;\;g,g'\in\Phi^{-1}\{h\}\implies \Phi(g^{-1}g')=1\implies gH=g'H$$

Comment: Thank you for those hints! The only step I do not understand is, from $ \Phi(g^{-1}g') = 1 $ to $ gH = g'H $

Comment: I thought to conclude g=g' would only be possible if $\Phi$ was injective

Comment: Yes @Jan, yet that is **not** the conclusion I hinted about in my answer.

Comment: I hope at one point I am ready to see what's going on and everything starts making sense. Right now I'm stuck. I just see so many possibilities and I do not know where to go. The only thing i know is, that if $ k \in \ker(\Phi) $ and $\ker(\Phi) \vartriangleleft G \Rightarrow gkg^{-1} \in \ker(\Phi) $ . Assuming $ gkg^{-1} = k' \Rightarrow gk=k'g \Rightarrow gk=gk' \Rightarrow k=k' $ But that does not even include any $h \in H$. @Timbuc What is the conclusion you hinted about in your answer?

Comment: @Jan, you already almost have it!: $$\Phi(g^{-1}g')=1\implies g^{-1}g'\in K:=\ker\Phi\implies g'=gK\implies \exists\,k\in K\;\;s.t.\;\;g'=gk$$and we have the existence. Now, uniqueness: $$g'=gk=g\overline k\implies k=\overline k$$and we're done.

Comment: .@Timbuc, How do you get from $ g,g' \in \Phi^{-1}\(\{h\}) $ to $ \Phi(g{-1}g')=1 $ ? I cannot really see the bridge. I think my problem is, that I cannot grab the meaning of $ g,g' \in \Phi^{-1}\(\{h\}) $.

Comment: @Jan Definition of inverse image (not to confuse with *inverse function*!): $$g,g'\in\Phi^{-1}(h)\implies \Phi(g)=h=\Phi(g')\implies \Phi(g)^{-1}\Phi(g)=1$$ But since we have a **group homomorphism** here, we get $\;\Phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(g^{-1})\;$, so in fact we have $$1=\Phi(g)^{-1}\phi(g')=\Phi(g^{-1})\Phi(g')=\Phi(g^{-1}g')$$ .

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $k=g^{-1}g'$ is in $\ker \Phi$ and $g'=gk$ and by the unicity of its form $k$ is unique

Comment: I know that $ k = g^{-1}g' \in \ker(\Phi) $ because I need to show that $ g'=gk $ which means by definition $ g^{-1}g'=g^{-1}gk $ ?